# Probability of picking the highest number from set of 3 random numbers

Tags: probability

Let there be a set of 3 random numbers. I need to calculate the probability of picking up the highest number. The question is very simple and I know that answer is 1/3. However, today I got a bit experimental and drew a flow diagram to know about the probability. According to this diagram, probability of picking a certain number is always higher than the remaining two. Please point out the mistake in my approach.

[image: Whats the issue]

Comment: Maybe it would clarify matters if you wrote out the argument you have in mind.  As it stands, I'm not even sure what you are claiming.

Comment: You have to show us the flow diagram.  How can we point out your mistake if you don't show us your work?

Comment: Knowing that $A>B$, there are only three possibilities.  $A>B>C,A>C>B, C>A>B$.  Thus, conditioned on $A>B$, the probability that $A>C$, say, is $\frac 23$.  Does that clarify things?

Comment: In short:  it's a bit hard to follow your logic, but you appear to be assuming that $A>B$ and $A>C$ are independent events.  They are not.

Comment: I tried to upload the picture, but the site only takes jpg and png files.  It is also very light and hard to read.

Comment: Your flowchart will make sense if you introduce a third layer: $B>C$ on the left half, $A>C$ on the right. Two outcomes will be impossible and each letter will be largest twice out of six possible outcomes. Per Ross' answer below, the leftmost branch lumps together $A>B>C$ and $A>C>B$

Answer (score 1):

Your error is to assume that the chance in the second comparison is $\frac 12$.  When you first compare $A$ with $B$ there is nothing to choose between them and you would expect the chance for each to be larger to be $\frac 12$.  When you compare the larger with $C$ it has a $\frac 23$ chance of winning, giving $\frac 13$ for the larger overall and (adding in the other branch) $\frac 13$ for $C$.

You can see this by taking the six different orderings for the three numbers and following them through your tree.  The left branch gets $A \gt C \gt B$ and $A \gt B \gt C$ for a chance of $\frac 13$

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your random distribution is continuous; then we don't have to worry about what happens when numbers are equal, because there is zero probability of that happening.

You have three random numbers. In the first step you compare two of them.
You then compare the *greater* of these two numbers with the third number.

When you compare a number to another number picked randomly from the set of three,
then you have a $50$-$50$ chance of either number being greater.
But when you compare a number to another number that has *already* been found to be greater than another number in the set, you no longer have a $50$-$50$ chance.
The number that has *already* been found to be greater than another number
has a better than $50\%$ chance to be greater than the new challenger.
In fact, it has a $2/3$ chance to be greater.

So at the bottom of your diagram, you have two events labeled $C,$ but they're each half as likely as either the event labeled $A$ or the event labeled $B.$
When you combine the two $C$ events together, each label has equal likelihood.

---

Granted, the $2/3$ chance may not be intuitive, though it can be worked out using the mathematics of probability.
But the fact that a particular number has *already exceeded* another number from the same distribution should intuitively give you a reason to believe that this number is more likely to be one of the greater numbers in the distribution than one of the lesser numbers, and that it has a better than $50\%$ chance to be greater than the next number you pick.

Answer (score 0):

There are six permutations of three numbers: $ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB, CBA$. And the probability of $A$ being the largest is:
$$P(A>B \ \ \text{and} \ \ A>C)=\frac26=\frac13$$

Now, let's see why the second comparisons depend on the first. Use the conditional probability:
$$P(A>C|A>B)=\frac{P(A>C \ \ \text{and} \ \ A>B)}{P(A>B)}=\frac{1/3}{1/2}=\frac23.$$
The same way you can work out other probabilities.